# How to integrate BIRT with Python

Tags: java, python, reporting, birt

Has anyone ever tried that?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of integration are you talking about?

If you want to call some BIRT API the I gues it could be done from Jython as Jython can call any Java API.

If you don't need to call the BIRT API then you can just get the birt reports with http requests from the BIRT report server (a tomcat application).

Comment: I'd like to develop a web based reporting solution in python and would like to use BIRT to generate reports. I don't really need to use extensively the BIRT API except to specify the rptdesign file, the report parameters and the ouput format.